# Trying to understand device tree entry for usart

Tags: linux, interrupt, device-tree

I'm pretty new to device tree programming, I'm trying to understand the `interrupts` line that shows up in the device tree for SAMA5D36 USART dts definition:

```
usart2: serial@f8020000 {
    compatible = "atmel,at91sam9260-usart";
    reg = <0xf8020000 0x100>;
    interrupts = <14 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH 5>;
    dmas = <&dma1 2 AT91_DMA_CFG_PER_ID(7)>, <&dma1 2 (AT91_DMA_CFG_PER_ID(8) | AT91_DMA_CFG_FIFOCFG_ASAP)>;
    dma-names = "tx", "rx";
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_usart2>;
    clocks = <&usart2_clk>;
    clock-names = "usart";
    status = "disabled";
};
```

What I think it means is that the interrupt will be level-high triggered. The interrupt is registered as interrupt 14. And the 5... I'm guessing is a priority? I've looked around and one of the things that confuses me is that for some examples out there, the order of these 3 entries seems to vary. Sometimes the trigger type will be the third entry instead of the second. My purpose in trying to understand this, is that I would like to experiment with adjusting the priority of this interrupt (looking for better responsiveness), but I don't even know whether to increase or decrease the value.

(P.S. Is there a better exchange to ask this question in?)